# Pode ter algum erro na execução de foreach nste método?

Tags: c#, .net, foreach

A execução do código abaixo pode ocorrer algum erro?

```
protected void ImprimeValores(Ilist<int> values) {
    if (values.Count > 0 && values != null)
        {
            foreach(int v in values) 
                Console.WriteLine(string.Concat("value:", v));
        }
}
```

Comment: A resposta resolveu o seu problema? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Se não souber como faz, veja o [tour]. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você e dar uma indicação que houve uma solução satisfatória. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 4):

Não posso falar sobre a lógica correta porque não sei o que deve fazer, mas há um erro básico do código em si. É possível ter um erro de referência nula, dado a característica da condição ser [*short-circuit*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation), isto pode ser facilmente resolvido com a inversão da condição:

```
protected void ImprimeValores(Ilist<int> values) => if (values != null && values.Count > 0) foreach(int v in values) WriteLine(string.Concat("value:", v));
```

Pra falar a verdade acho desnecessário verificar se `values` é maior que zero, a não ser que depois pretenda fazer algo diferente, neste código, é redundância. Também acho completamente desnecessário usar o método de concatenação (o compilador fará isto por você). Não está errado, tem gente que gosta.

Nem falei do erro de sintaxe, este o compilador já mostra.

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/bz1y6W). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PAb95I). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Algorithm/ShortCircuit.cs).

Também é possível mudar este `if` por um contrato e evitar a verificação em tempo de execução em muitos casos, mas isto já é outro assunto.

Comment: obrigado... fiz o teste aqui e realmente recebi o erro de referência nula...
quanto as outras partes, também corrigi.

Comment: O foreach só será executado caso `values.Count > 0 `, não precisa checkar no if.

Comment: @JoãoSobral leia a resposta toda.

Comment: A que erro de sintaxe você se refere?

Comment: @ramaral `ilist`.